# Why does FireMonkey CopyStartUpFiles fail on an iPad 2 Device?

Tags: ios, firemonkey

In the System.StartUpCopy code below, DirectoryExists(Source) returns false.

```
{$IF Defined(IOS)}
  Source := UTF8ToString(Bundle.bundlePath.UTF8String) + PathDelim + 'StartUp' + PathDelim;
{$ENDIF IOS}
  if DirectoryExists(Source) then
    DoCopyFiles(Source, Destination);
```

This is on Tokyo 10.2 and Berlin 10.1 using a 32-bit app in "development mode" targeting an iPad 2 using SDK 10.2. The iPad 2 is running IOS 9.3.5

The debugger shows the value of "Source" is:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application//Project1.app/Startup/

The deployment and provisioning all appear to be ok and the above code works when targeting the IOS simulator. The Startup directory does exist in the Project1.app in the PAServer folder on the Mac. Any clues what could cause the bundlePath to not be found?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question...

It turns out that the same code, executed later in one of my own unit initialization sections succeeds, so something's not happening at the right time in the FireMonkey startup code.

In any event, I can now simply read my own deployed files directly from the bundle using the above code. The Startup/Documents copy feature appears to be redundant on IOS and just adds to the app's startup time.